# I keep running into so many different synonyms for like/dislike on Chinese websites. What others am I missing?

Tags: synonyms

Like: 好文, 顶一下, 喜欢, 赞, 支持

Dislike: 踩一下, 太水, 反对

Answer (score 2):

Like：鲜花（flowers）

Dislike：板砖（bricks）